# Позиционирование фона от правого края

Tags: css

Мне нужно спозиционировать фоновое изображение таким образом, чтобы правая половина экрана была без фона, а левая половина была с фоновой картинкой.

```
background-position: bottom 200px right 50% !important;
```

Работает неадекватно и фон ставится по центру блока. Задача вроде легкая но туплю

Нужно именно, чтобы не менялся оригинальный размер фоновой картинки, а лишнее просто заходило за левый край экрана

Comment: может нужно по левому краю без отступа?

Comment: @codename0082016 Ну фон должен быть слева, при этом не налезать на правую половину

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фон слева, справа ничего, правый край всегда находится по середине. Достигается этот эффект при помощи сдвига на 50 вьюпорт-единиц от правого края.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(http://placeimg.com/1200/1200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 50vw top;
}
```

Comment: Не подходит. Потому, что на небольших экранах фон становится совсем мелким. Нужно именно, чтобы не менялся оригинальный размер фоновой картинки, а лишнее просто заходило за левый край

Comment: Дополните вопрос, потому что это требование не очевидно.

Comment: см. обновленный ответ.

Comment: То, что нужно..

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так:

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
div:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg');
  background-position: center right;
  background-size: inherit;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: С дополнительным элементом не интересно :-)

Comment: @sasha-omelchenko пфф! Да! затупила, у вас без лишнего)