# Как прижать два фоновых изображения к центру?

Tags: css3, изображения, position, background

У меня есть блок ширина у которого 100%, я задал два фонофых изображения.
Мне нужно, что б они прижались к центру и не растягивались.

```
.about_us{
    min-height: 581px;
    background: url('/img/who.png') no-repeat,
                url('/img/about_us_back.png')$green  no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% cover;
    background-position: right,left;
}
```

Comment: Вот здесь описан способ так сделать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655200/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 0):

Только у меня, если задать 50vw, между изображениями оставалось еще место.

```
.about_us{
min-height: 581px;
background: url('/img/who.png') no-repeat,
            url('/img/about_us_back.png')$green  no-repeat;
background-position: left 49.5vw top,right 49.5vw top;
}
```